# Failed to Listen on the Given Port .net core 2.0 IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I am trying to publish a .netcore 2.0 application to a remote web server and host it using IIS. I have a custom domain setup and want to run it as www.mysub.mydomain.com. It is a web api application.

I have published the app to the server and when I run dotnet on the project manually, it runs. It runs off of localhost:5000 when I do this, and when I navigate to it on the server it works properly.

The problem comes when I try to run it via IIS after binding www.mysub.mydomain.com to the location. I get a 502.5 Process Failure error in my browser.

When I check the Event Viewer, I see that it says "created process with commandline 'dotnet .\myproj.dll' but failed to listen on the given port '21159'"

Any ideas?

Comment: There's probably a conflict with another application or website already using that port.

Comment: TcpView is a good tool to check that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: can you provide more details about steps of how you hosted in IIS? Also, check the below official Microsoft doc to host .net core app in IIS and make sure you followed all the steps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x